# Issue with more than two linters working on sublime 3

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3, jshint, htmltidy, csslint

I'm running sublime 3084 OSX 10.10.3 and i have three tabs open, one html document, one css and one javascript file. I have linters for all three installed but whenever I open the program only the css linter (csslint) and either the html or the javascript linter, but not both, work. If I open the program with the javascript tab open, that linter works. If I open the program with the html document open, that linter works. csslint works regardless. Does anyone know of this issue or possible bug? If so I would greatly appreciate some help, it's really frustrating.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you running these linters independently, or as subprocesses of SublimeLinter?

Comment: I'm sorry could you elaborate?

Comment: Do you have separate linters installed, or are you using [`SublimeLinter`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeLinter) with sub-packages like [`SublimeLinter-csslint`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeLinter-csslint), [`SublimeLinter-jshint`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeLinter-jshint), and [`SublimeLinter-html-tidy`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeLinter-html-tidy), for example. They don't have to be those exact packages, but please [edit] your question and include links to the linter packages you **are** using.

Comment: Thanks yes I'm using sublimeLinter with those exact sub-packages and all the files are placed in the correct directory. Even in the console in sublime says all three were successfully activated and there's only one warning: File "/Users/Jonny/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/SublimeLinter/lint/linter.py", line 1492, in can_lint
    status = 'WARNING: {} deactivated, cannot locate \'{}\''.format(cls.name, executable)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'executable' referenced before assignment

Comment: I think the easiest thing to do at this point would be to first ensure that SL and all of its sub-linters are up-to-date: Open the Command Palette, type ***`pcu`***, and ensure that none of the packages is listed there. If one or more are, click on them to upgrade them, then see if the problem returns. If it does, I'd file a complete [issue](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter3/issues) with the SL devs, and probably with the `html-tidy` and `jshint` devs as well (you can find links on the Package Control pages above). Include as much detail as possible, making sure (...)

Comment: (...) you turn on any debugging options in the preferences that may be there. I haven't used SL in a while, so I don't remember exactly how to do it, but I'm pretty sure the option is there.